# Reading data from a file in Python

Tags: python, string, int

I have a data file that looks like this:

```
1,100
2,200
3,-400
4,500
```

As you can see, each data point has 2 components
When I do file.readlines() they all come up as strings such as '1,100\n' so I am wondering how would I make them into integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read line by line and then split each line:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        a, b = [int(x) for x in line.split(',')]
        # here you can use a and b as numbers
```

The above has the advantage of using the `with` statement, which takes care of automatically closing the file even in the event of an error.

Answer (score 4):

This is comma separated data so using the csv module is a good approach.

Simple version to extract the string data

```
import csv
with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for a, b in reader:
        print a, b
```

or with Thomas's approach to cast data to integers

```
import csv
with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        a, b = map(int, line)
        print a, b
```

Comment: While this looks like unnecessary overhead, the `csv` module will save you a lot of pain as you begin to deal with more complicated data loading problems.

Answer (score 2):

You might do:

```
map(int, line.strip().split(','))
```

Here's what this does

1. `line.strip()` converts `"1,100\n"` to `"1,100"`
2. `line.split(',') converts`"1,100"`to`("1", "100")`
3. `map(int, ...)` applies `int` to each argument, and returns `(1, 100)`

Comment: Not necessary to `strip`. `int` function ignores newline characters for you. Good answer though so +1.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [numpy.loadtxt()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) for that:

```
import numpy
numpy.loadtxt("yourFileName.txt", dtype=int, delimiter=",")
```